# Laravel Middleware exception returns json

Tags: laravel, laravel-middleware

Somewhere in my app I have made a change so that whenever a middleware faces an exception it return json.

```
Route::get('/profile/edit', 'UserController@edit')->middleware('auth');
```

I want it to redirect to /login however it returns `{"error":"Unauthenticated"}`.

I can't find where I have made the change... Any Ideas? :)

Comment: Did you override an exception handler in a controller constructor?

Comment: Start using xdebug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have probably edited `app\Exceptions\Handler.php`

Comment: my gosh :) Thanks!